# How to reproject Network Dataset from GCS_WGS_1984 to Web Mercator?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, coordinate-system, network-analyst

I need to know how to change the coordinate system of my feature dataset with its network dataset from **GCS_WGS_1984** to **Web Mercator**.

Once I know how to do this, I would like to make a tool in Python or ModelBuilder because I need to do it many times.

Comment: If it's a raster you'll need to use ProjectRaster_management()

Comment: OP's question is discussing network datasets, not rasters.

Answer (score 4):

there is a single tool to do it in ArcGIS, called project(management). You can right click on the tool to launch it in batch mode. If you want to do it in Python, here is the command line :

```
outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference(3785) #the code for WGS84 Web Mercator
arcpy.Project_management(infc, outfc, outCS)
```

Comment: I used the project tool but gives me this error Might you help me 

000210 Error: Can not create output <value> 

description 
The output can not be created. Potential Reasons include data locking, an incorrect path, and limited access rights.

Comment: you need to project in a new feature dataset. Is this what you did ?

Comment: yes a feature dataset

Comment: you need to take each feature class separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Project](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm) tool which:

> Projects spatial data from one coordinate system to another.

but be aware that (with my bolding):

> When projecting the complex data types listed below, certain
>   operations need to be performed on the resulting data:
>
> - Feature dataset containing a network dataset: the **network dataset must be rebuilt**.